# Не могу подключится к серверу на asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Я пишу мобильное приложение на MAUI и мне нужно подключится к серверу через интернет чтобы получать данные. Так же не могу подключится через по локальной сети через эмулятор андроида MAUI. Выбивает эту ошибку:

```
System.Net.WebException: 'Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7297'
```

Сам код подключения:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7297/api/Products/getcategories");
        var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

client это сам HttpClient который закэширован в самом классе.
Еще хотелось бы узнать как заставить работать сервер по статическому ip.

Comment: Разрешение на доступ в сеть приложению надо выдать

Comment: вам надо ваш api захостить на IP вашего компа , если комп на 192.168.0.45, то https://192.168.0.45:7297/api/ , так как эмулятор не видит localhost

Comment: А где это можно указать? В launchSettings? Могу ли я указать свой статический ip?

Comment: почитайте: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/maui/data-cloud/local-web-services

Comment: Пытаюсь подключится через curl на самом пк по https://192.168.0.112:443/api/Products/getcategories
и говорит что не может подключится к серверу так же и через эмулятор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый и самый простой вариант исправления этой ошибки — это использовать Docker.
Доку по нему здесь:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Второй вариант тоже не особо сложный. Нужно просто настроить Kestrel. Если кратко то это кроссплатформенный сервер.
Вот в этой доке

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0

более четко расписано как его настроить, но мне хватило лишь одного шага.
Это добавить несколько строчек кода:

```
        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
        {
            serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(5005, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps();
            });
        });
        builder.WebHost.UseKestrel();
```

Позже будет warn в самой консоли:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
  Overriding address(es) 'https://localhost:5001/, http://localhost:5000/'. Binding to endpoints defined via IConfiguration and/or UseKestrel() instead.
```

Чтобы это исправить нужно добавить строку в launchsettings.json в конфигурацию с названием вашего проекта или с названием Kestrel

```
"externalUrlConfiguration": true
```

После этого сервер будет работать как нужно. В моем случае на статическом IP.